# How do I store the data from DTO Gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm, fibers

I am using golang fiber and GORM. I am trying to store the data from DTO. For example, I have created a post entity and post dto like below.

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
    Address string
    Phone string
}
```

This is my DTO

```
type PostDto struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Address string `json:"address"`
    Phone string `json:"phone"`
}
```

I am trying to store the data like below

```
var postDto models.PostDto
c.BodyParser(&postDto)
err := database.DB.Model(models.User{}).Create(&postDto).Error
fmt.Println(err.Error())
```

But I am getting the below error

```
panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Field on string Value
```

Could anyone help to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what you are  doing? this is go language, not java, why do you define two structs?

You can use tag to complete that you want.

```golang
type User struct {
    gorm.Model `json:"-" gorm:"-"`
    Name string `json:"name" gorm:"column:name"`
    Address string `json:"address" gorm:"column:address"`
    Phone string `json:"phone"  gorm:"column:phone"`
}


var user User
err := database.DB.Model(User{}).Create(&user).Error
fmt.Println(err.Error())
```

Answer (score 2):

User and PostDto structures are not same, using one model to get and save data from another is wrong.

**Either** create a function to convert from PostDto to User, adn use its output in Create

```
func (postDTo PostDTo) ToUser() *User {
    return &User{Name: postDTo.Name, Address: postDTo.Address, Phone: postDTo.Phone}
}
```

**OR**, as `User` and `PostDto` structs are so similar, add json ignore to `gorm.Model` in `User` and use it instead of `PostDto`

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model `json:"-"`
    Name       string `json:"name"`
    Address    string `json:"address"`
    Phone      string `json:"phone"`
}


var postData models.User
c.BodyParser(&postData)
```